# Select an element with LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the following XML.

```
<logs version="1.3.1.1" xmlns="http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131">
    <log uidWell="001" uidWellbore="001" uid="0c43e8df-ed63-41e4-878f-d1e5dd3b97d1">
        <startIndex uom="m">200.29</startIndex>
        <endIndex uom="m">209.73</endIndex>
        <logCurveInfo>
            <mnemonic>hkldAv1</mnemonic>
        </logCurveInfo>
        <logCurveInfo>
            <mnemonic>DEPTH</mnemonic>
        </logCurveInfo>
        <logCurveInfo>
            <mnemonic>wobAv1</mnemonic>
        </logCurveInfo>
        <logCurveInfo>
            <mnemonic>ropAv1</mnemonic>
        </logCurveInfo>
        <logData />
    </log>
</logs>
```

I want to retrieve the element `<logData>` from the XML.

I have tried with,

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\data.xml");
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131";
XElement xlog = xDoc.Element(xmlns + "logData");
```

But it is returning null for `xlog`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go deeper in the hierarchy using `Descendants()`, like this:

```
  var xlogs = xDoc.Descendants(xmlns + "logData");
```

Which will give you an enumerable with all logData.